# Empty Set versus Set containing only zero

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if I have a two sets $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\leq0\}$ and $T=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:y\geq0\}$ then would the intersection $S\cap T=\{0\}$ be considered an empty set?

More explicitly is it correct to state $\{0\} = \emptyset$?

Comment: Not quite. The empty set contains no elements, while $\{0\}$ contains one, namely, $0$.

Comment: That's what I thought but I just wanted to make sure. Thank you!

Comment: A set that contains *something* cannot be empty.

Comment: To be pedantic, in some ways of rigorously defining the natural numbers using sets, we can define the natural number zero, $0$, as the empty set $\{\}$, and recursively define all other natural numbers as $n:=(n-1)\cup\{(n-1)\}$, i.e. the numbers $0,1,2,\dots$ are $\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\},\dots$, so in a very pedantic sense $\{0\}$ can be said to equal the natural number $1$.

Comment: Not *quite*??? Is that like "not quite" pregnant.  Either a set has elements or it doesn't.  And 0 is an element.  It's a bit weird to say 0 is "not quite" non-existant.